Problemas con servidor sftp y Filezilla (archivos ocultos)
cree un servidor Sftp con centos 7, los permisos de usuarios y directorios quedaron bien, pero al momento de ingresar al servidor via Filezilla aparecen los archivos como son ".bash_profile" ".bash_logout" que en realidad no deberian aparecer.
No se me ocurre alguna solución,
desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda


Según la documentación, esto no se puede hacer por defecto. Sin embargo el cliente, Filezilla tiene unos filtos que puedes activar para no ver esos archivos. En menú Ver - Filtros de listado de directorio.... Del panel de la derecha, selecciona Configuration files, Aplicas, aceptas y ya no se verán esos archivos.
